# How many days since sign up in mysql with new column

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to add a column to my database which displays the amount of time in days since a user signed up.

Currently I have a field which displays the date they signed up in unix.

Is it possible for the new column to increase its fields by 1 each day?

Comment: Why bother? You can get this through easy sql.

Comment: Could you please tel me how?

Comment: This sounds like a really dumb idea.

Comment: You sound like a really dumb idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basic SQL to get this information for you dynamically. [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) will be what you need:

```
SELECT 
   DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, FROM_UNIXTIME(date_signed_up)) AS days_since_signup
FROM
    tablename
```

Comment: SELECT 
   DATEDIFF(`joined`, CURRENT_DATE) AS `days_since_signup`
FROM
    phpfox_user

Comment: Do you have `null` in any of your rows?

Comment: No sir. The 'joined' column has data in every celll.

Comment: Hmm. That definitely is the right query. Try wrapping `joined` in ticks `

Comment: Should DATEDIFF be in red text? Thank you for your help.

Comment: That depends on your editor. It is a built in MySQL function so if your editor highlights functions then it will be in a special color.

Comment: Joined is an INT rather than a date, is there a way to convert it first? That might be why I'm getting this error.

Comment: That will do it. Is it a timestamp? If it is see my updated answer.

Comment: It worked great, thank you SO much! I'm assuming this won't update the cells each day, so how would I go about making it increase by 1 each day?

Comment: It automatically updates each day as `current_date` will always reflect the current day. So you never have to change anything. It just works automatically.

Answer (score 0):

current time - timestamp_of_registration:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURTIME(), SIGNUP_DATE);
```